# Watermarking the video streaming written in go language with "github.com/blackjack/webcam" library

Tags: go, video-streaming, v4l2, video-watermarking

I want to watermark "the video streaming over http" which is written in GO language by using [blackjack](http://github.com/blackjack/webcam) library. And for this, I found a code [watermarking with png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100023/manipulating-watermark-images-with-go). But I could not manage to transform the variables jpeg <-> byte[].

Here is the code part which gets the frame from cam and writes to "JpegImage" variable.

```
var jpegImage []byte   
frame, err := cam.ReadFrame()
if len(frame) != 0 {
    mutex.Lock()
    jpegImage = frame
    mutex.Unlock()
} 
else if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
```

And here is the watermarking code with "image.jpg" variable.

```
imgb, _ := os.Open("image.jpg")
img, _ := jpeg.Decode(imgb)
defer imgb.Close()

wmb, _ := os.Open("watermark.png")
watermark, _ := png.Decode(wmb)
defer wmb.Close()

offset := image.Pt(200, 200)
b := img.Bounds()
m := image.NewRGBA(b)
draw.Draw(m, b, img, image.ZP, draw.Src)
draw.Draw(m, watermark.Bounds().Add(offset), watermark, image.ZP, draw.Over)

imgw, _ := os.Create("watermarked.jpg")
jpeg.Encode(imgw, m, &jpeg.Options{jpeg.DefaultQuality})
defer imgw.Close()
```

In the end, I need to combine this two code parts. After getting the frame from cam; firstly transform it to jpg, secondly watermark with png, thirdly transform it to []byte and lastly assign it to "JpegImage" variable.

I hope you can help me please.